# Correct working process with Entity Framework Code-First and GitFlow

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, git-flow

We have started new project with Entity Framework Code-First and want to use a bit simplified GitFlow process - each new feature has own branch.

Team consists of 1 team lead who review all pull request and 3 developers who implement the tasks.

Each developer connects to his-own DB and can change DB and add migrations into project it task requires this.

I see the issue in next situations:

1. Developer A starts "Task 1" and creates new Branch "task_1"
2. Developer A finish "Task 1" and creates pull request to merge branch "task_1" into master
3. Team lead switch to branch "task_1" to verify the code
4. Team lead update DB via update-database and apply migration which Developer A made for "Task 1"
5. On the same time Developer B finished his "Task 2" and created pull request to merge his branch "task_2" to master.
6. Team lead reject Developer's A pull request and switch to the branch "task_2" to verify what Developer B has done.

And on this moment we have an issue because developers A and B started their branches on the same time and each of their branches contains their-own migrations but Team Lead's DB the only one DB for all branches.

Use database initialization strategy DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges is not a case because it will drop all data together with DB. We use custom migrations configuration

```
public class CheckAndMigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TContext, TMigrationsConfiguration> :
        IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>
        where TContext : DbContext where TMigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext>, new()
    {
        public virtual void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
        {
            var migratorBase = (MigratorBase)new DbMigrator(Activator.CreateInstance<TMigrationsConfiguration>());
            if (migratorBase.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
            {
                migratorBase.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

What would you suggest to do or maybe change development process to allow for Team Lead verify different branches and for developer to switch between branches.

Thank you for the help

Comment: The solution is easy. Always before switch to another branch need update database to common migration.